# a shortcut to extract a tuple in a function paramenter in scala

Tags: scala

```
val list = List((1,2), (3,4))

list.map(tuple => {
  val (a, b) = tuple
  do_something(a,b)
})

// the previous can be shortened as follows
list.map{ case(a, b) =>
  do_something(a,b)
}

// similarly, how can I shorten this (and avoid declaring the 'tuple' variable)?
def f(tuple: (Int, Int)) {
  val (a, b) = tuple
  do_something(a,b)
}

// here there two ways, but still not very short,
// and I could avoid declaring the 'tuple' variable
def f(tuple: (Int, Int)) {
  tuple match {
    case (a, b) => do_something(a,b)
  }
}

def f(tuple: (Int, Int)): Unit = tuple match {
  case (a, b) => do_something(a,b)
}
```

Comment: That's the simplest form you can have in scala.

Comment: F# treats all arguments to a function as single tuple. Would be awesome if Scala could do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tupled`

```
scala> def doSomething = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
doSomething: (Int, Int) => Int

scala> doSomething.tupled((1, 2))
res0: Int = 3

scala> def f(tuple: (Int, Int)) = doSomething.tupled(tuple)
f: (tuple: (Int, Int))Int

scala> f((1,2))
res1: Int = 3

scala> f(1,2) // this is due to scala auto-tupling
res2: Int = 3
```

`tupled` is defined for every `FunctionN` with `N >= 2`, and returns a function expecting the parameters wrapped in a tuple.

Comment: I called `do_something(a,b)` inside `f()` just as an example. I actually don't want to create the external function `do_something`. so, I am looking for a more readable version of `def f(tuple: (Int, Int)) = tuple._1 + tuple._2`. (by more readable, I mean giving variable names instead of using the _1 an _2 on the tuple).

Answer (score 0):

While this might look like a trivial suggestion, the `f` function, can be further simplified by just using `_1` and `_2` on a tuple.

```
def f(tuple: (Int, Int)): Unit = 
    do_something(tuple._1, tuple._2)
```

Obviously by doing this you're affecting readability (some meta-information about the meaning of the 1st and 2nd parameter of the tuple is removed) and should you wish to use elements of the tuple somewhere else in the `f` method you will need to extract them again.

Though for many uses this might be still the easiest, shortest and most intuitive alternative.

Comment: this would be like using `list.map(tuple => do_something(tupple._1, tupple._2))`. it is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to pass a tuple to a method with 2 args?

```
def f(tuple: (Int,Int)) = do_something(tuple._1, tuple._2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> by more readable, I mean giving variable names instead of using the _1 an _2 on the tuple

In this case, it's a good idea to use a case class instead of a tuple, especially since it only takes one line:

```
case class IntPair(a: Int, b: Int)

def f(pair: IntPair) = do_something(pair.a, pair.b)
```

If you get `(Int, Int)` from external code which can't be changed (or you don't want to change), you could add a method converting from a tuple to `IntPair`.

Another option: `{(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}.tupled.apply(tuple)`. Unfortunately, `{case (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b}.apply(tuple)` doesn't work.